# Open a GPX file in my iPhone app, from Safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I would like users to be able to click links in Safari that are GPX files, and import them into my app.

I have this sort of working - there are some websites I can go to, click a GPX file, and it will give me the option to open in my app.

However, some GPX files, including a simple GPX file that I am hosting on my local machine, won't open in this way. What might I have done wrong in registering for the GPX file type?

Here is my plist code:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>GPSXML File</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>gaia-icon.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.utf8-plain-text</string>
            <string>com.apple.dt.document.gpx</string>
            <string>com.trailbehind.gpx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.trailbehind.gpx</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>text/plain; charset=UTF-8</string>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>gpx</string>
        </dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.content</string>
            <string>public.item</string>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.xml</string>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>GPSXML</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
  <true/>
```

Comment: I suspect the difference between the sites that work and don't is the MIME type they are serving the file with.  Retrieve the whole HTTP response including the headers from both kinds of site and compare the "Content-Type" headers which should reveal what's going on.  I'm answering this from first HTTP principles rather than from any expertise about URL handling in iOS apps so that's about as far as I can go with this.

Comment: Does the solution you had in the end still work on iOS13? If so, I'd be super happy if you could share what you did

Answer (score 1):

One thing that definitely needs update is:

```
<key>public.filename-extension</key>
<string>gpx</string>
```

should be

```
<key>public.filename-extension</key>
<array>
    <string>gpx</string>
</array>
```

according to the Troubleshooting Tips from https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html